# IsTabStop="False" has no effect on my WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, tabstop

I'm having a really hard time with something that should be trivial. I just want to remove a few buttons from the tab order on a UserControl. I've tried adding `IsTabStop="False"` and `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"` attributes to their xaml declarations, as well as setting `myButton.IsTabStop = false;` in the Loaded event handler for the UserControl. None of these additions had any effect, I could still tab to the controls I did this for.

Setting the TabIndex in the xaml works fine. The UserControl is being displayed in a WPFElementHost if that might make a difference. The other thought I had was that I might need to specify the TabIndex for all the other controls, but I haven't read that anywhere and I'd prefer to not state that explicitly if possible. Does anyone have a guess as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Does setting `Focusable="False"` make any difference?

Comment: Normally IsTabStop works fine, w/o ElementHost

Comment: Good thought, but `Focusable="False"` did not change the behavior. I can still tab to the button in question. Also, I tried it in combination with the `IsTabStop="False"` attribute, as well as by itself.

Comment: So I realized that the buttons I'm trying to remove from the tab order were actually buttons nested inside custom UserControls, so I was setting the UserControls' IsTabStop property, but the inner button wasn't aware of the change. This solved part of the problem, but I am still unable to remove several ListBoxes from the tab order - they ignore my attempts.

Comment: Similar scenario: a `ListBox`.  While empty, `.IsTabStop=false` is enough to exclude it from tab-sequence.  Once its `.ItemsSource` is assigned, it is included.  Then data is reset, and it's not in sequence;  then data is set again - and it's in.  And again, and again..  Setting `.Focusable=false` in addition has no effect.

Comment: @Astrogator: hit probably the same problem with `UserControl` that has its `ItemsSource` assigned (and that probably resets `IsTabStop`).   Pretty unnerving.

Comment: @Astrogator: found a solution. Actually my problem was a little different as I had `UserControl` based on `ItemsControl` and kept setting `IsTabStop` on the user control to no avail when in fact my items control inside it kept getting focus with tab circulation. Setting `IsTabStop` on the items control solved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Try setting `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation ="None"` in the parent control.

Comment: That would disable all tabstops - not usable when some lements should be hit by tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need also employ
`KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation ="Continue"` for the parent controls, and

```
"Focusable=False"
```