# How can I prevent tabbing to a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus, keyboard-navigation

I have a custom Popup that overlays part of my screen. When it is open, I want to disable tabbing into the UserControl behind it. I do not want to use the `IsEnabled` property because I do not want to gray out all the controls.

Is there another property that does the same thing? `IsTabStop` only prevents the tab from stopping on the UserControl itself, not it's children, and `IsFocusable` isn't a valid property for a UserControl.

Comment: `Focusable` is a property on `UserControl` inherited from `UIElement`. Setting `Focusable="False"` and `IsHitTestVisible="False"` should solve your problem

Comment: @Meleak That does not work. I can still tab to the controls inside my UserControl

Comment: Does `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"` on your UserControl help? Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation.aspx)

Comment: @LPL I take it back, that does work :) I was setting my `KeyBoardNavigation.TabNavigation` inside my UserControl, so the trigger was having no effect. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: `IsTabStop` seems to not work on user controls that have `ItemsSource` assigned. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078937/istabstop-false-has-no-effect-on-my-wpf-app/8311213#comment42991524_5078937)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation.aspx) with [KeyboardNavigationMode.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode.aspx) on your container control.

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can bind `IsTabStop` on the child controls to `IsTabStop` on the `UserControl`.

That way, you only have to set it once.

Comment: I currently have 35 controls in my UserControl... I don't really want to create a binding on all of them, and have to remember to set that binding for new controls. Isn't there an easier way of disabling it on the UserControl level?

Comment: A loop? foreach (Control control in grid.Children)
            {
                control.IsTabStop = false;
            }

Comment: It'd have to be a loop that goes through all levels of child objects.... I suppose it's possible

Answer (score 0):

You could write an attached property that you would set in the top element.
That attached property would recursively set IsTabStop to false in all the child elements.

Let me know if you need any help getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind that property to the user control.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PDV.UserControls.InputField"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 // etc... then:                     
                 x:Name="Root" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" >

        <Grid>
           <TextBox Name="textBox"  
                TabIndex="{Binding Path=TabIndex, ElementName=Root}" 
                IsTabStop="{Binding Path=IsTabStop, ElementName=Root}"  />                
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"` seems to bubble up to all other parent containers in my case. This is maybe not wanted in some scenarios.
So I came up with a PreviewKeyDown-Event in code behind like this:

```cs
    private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            ((Control)sender).Focus(); 
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```cs
// ...

var applicationWindow = Application.Current?.MainWindow;
if (applicationWindow != null)
{
    KeyboardNavigation.SetIsTabStop(
        element: applicationWindow, 
        isTabStop: false);

    KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(
        element: applicationWindow, 
        mode: false);
}

// ...
```

---

Note: it is good to have a backup plan for restoring the Keyboard navigation in case if the above is needed only temporarily.